# Find the radius of a circle. A table top

Tags: geometry

A table is push into the corner of a square room, until two point on the edge of the table top touches the walls. It is found that a point on the intercepted arc between the two points is 17 and 28 units away from the closest walls. Find the radius of the table top.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to use coordinates? This is telling you that the point $(r - 28, r - 17)$ is on the circle, and therefore that it satisfies the equation for the circle (of radius $r$ and of center $(0, 0)$). Writing that down produces an equation that is easily solved for $r$.

Comment: You mean ${(r-28)}^2$+${(r-17)}^2$= ${r}^2$

Comment: And solve for r?

Comment: Then the answer is irrational

Comment: @user11355 Seems you've got it.

Comment: There is a problem, still. Sometimes, you could have two positive zeros. Which one is it?

Comment: Or they are both solutions. Why?

Comment: @user11355 I suppose they really are both solutions. My guess is that the other one is when the circle is centered inside the little rectangle that you've drawn at the top-right, so the lower-left of the circle is where it intercepts the point $(r - 28, r - 17)$.

Comment: But then the problem is asking for only one. Also, could we use the congrent tangent property of a circle.

Comment: @user11355 If the problem provides a drawing like the one you gave, then it seems the right answer would be the larger radius. Otherwise it's ambiguous, and you should put down both possible radii. I don't see how tangents are relevant, though.